# Using regex in php to just select and echo out persian chars

Tags: php, regex, string, function

I have a string like this :

```
این یafsک رشsegته می y34باشد
```

Specially , i want a function (like **regex**) to echo out JUST persian chars.

So , the out put should be :

```
این یک رشته می باشد
```

I have found we can use below regex, but i can't use it with function, it does not work.

**regex i tried:**

```
preg_match("(^[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]*$)", $title);
```

**error : Compilation failed: character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large at offset**

What can i do and what should i do ?

Tnx.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

سلام عزیزم

```
$string = preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $string);
```

You can simply remove all English alphabetical characters and all numbers from the string

OR : you can do it reverse :

```
$string  = preg_replace("/[^ الف-ی]/i", "", $string);
```

This will remove all characters except Persian chars , This way you can remove all persian numbers too : d

Comment: wow, tnx my dear friend, nice trick, sorry my reputation is low i can't vote up, + another problem is there any way to remove persian numbers too ?

Comment: Yeap 
I think my seccond recommendation will do the job ,

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable UTF-8 on the pattern to use the “higher” unicode range in a regex:

```
preg_match("/^[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]*$/u", $title);
```

Note the `u` modifier after the closing delimiter.

Comment: Tnx, But it's not working, It returns `0` for every every string.

Comment: If you want to *collect* the matches, you have to pass a third parameter to preg_match which is filled by reference. See https://php.net/preg_match. However, my solution fixes the “compilation failed” error. Everything else depends on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: If you want to remove them, see xe4me's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
preg_match("/^[الف-ی]*$/u", $title);
```